# How to replace form field with custom layout in Django?

Tags: django, forms, user-interface

I have a model form field which is a choice field. Instead of having the default widget:

[image]

I would like to have a grid of cards like so:

[image]

With each of the choices that would have been in the default widget in a card.

How do I edit the python form to achieve this?

Here is my form:

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class PostJobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Job
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'pay',
            'category'
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to move away from default django forms and create the forms using html, css and js the way you want.

When using django forms, it uses default templates.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="post" action"">
    <input type="text" id="id_title" name="title">
    <!--this input is for title field of your model form-->
</form>
```

as shown above you can do it for any field that you want
**IMP** keep the name attribute of input and that of model field same